# Will a motor be safe if i over voltage it a little bit?

Tags: voltage, motor

If i have a 7,4v motor (like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/322367179361) one), can i safely run it at 8v or 9v without shortening the lifespan or destroying the motor.

Comment: If it could it would be rated 8 or 9V instead.

Comment: This is a x-y problem. You should just find a faster motor rather than over driving this one. Driving the motor above it's speed rating would do more harm than simply over voltage.

Comment: The maker may not even spec "lifetime" (lifetime of stuff seems to be shorter than it used to, nowadays). A sane maker won't spec *anything* overload for an item like this. I'd guess 8-9 V would shorten life, but not destroy. The overload that causes destruction would be tested by you - buy a dozen extra if you really want to know.

Comment: Why are you using 8-9v?  Is this being used in a LiPo system?  If so, you should be "fine enough".  The voltage will sag down to a safe level for the motor quickly enough, and you're likely to destroy the (assumed) RC model before the motor burns itself out.  And on the off-chance that the motor outlasts your model -- congrats, you got thousands of hours of lifespan exceeding the performance specifications of a $4 part.

Comment: FWIW, I was just looking at my <30 year old Lego motors.  They appear to be rated at 4v, yet the associated battery boxes take 3x 1.5v C cell batteries for a total of 4.5v.  The motors are still working fine (with the addition of a spot of WD40).

Comment: you can use a power dioide to drop off some volts before it gets to the motor...

Comment: That much extra voltage is *probably* safe in the sense that with a little extra voltage it probably won't explode immediately or burst into flames.  However you'll wear the motor out quicker, perhaps much much quicker.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma - But 3 C cells won't put out 4.5v for more than about 2 minutes.

Comment: You would probably get away with it, especially if you did not run at full voltage most of the time.  Not something you should do if you're designing a product, however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just hooking it up to a higher voltage can deliver more current than the motor is rated for. That will reduce the lifespan of the motor and, if the current is high enough, cause it to fail.

However, there are a number of separate issues with DC motors.

1. Over Current. As I mentioned above, too high a current will overheat the coil and if it gets hot enough, it will burn out or seize the motor. Too much current can also affect the magnetics in the stator.
2. Over voltage. The windings in the coil have an insulation rating that will fail if the voltage is high enough causing arcing and again, burn out. Further, the brushes will arc more at higher voltages causing heat and faster wear.
3. Over speed. DC motors are not the best mechanical beasts in the world. Brushes rubbing on the commutator and often poor bearings means over speed will significant reduce the lifespan of the motor.

Having said all that, the number one issue is over-current.

**CONTROLLED OVER-DRIVE**

Motor rating plates are defined for a static..."Apply a voltage and go" setup.

If you limit the current to the motor you can in fact drive it at much higher voltages and speeds without significantly over-heating the motor.

This is because one of the governing factors of the current taken by a motor is the speed of the motor itself. The back EMF generated by the motor as it spins reduces the current you can deliver at any given terminal voltage.

In theory, if say the rated current of the motor is 1A, and your motor drives the load at max speed using less current than that, it is possible to increase the terminal voltage, and hence the speed, until the point where the rated current reaches that 1A level. **This must of course be done while limiting the current to that 1A value.**

However, there are limits to this. Obviously you can not exceed the breakdown voltage of the coil, but also you have to remember there are switching inductors inside the motor. These form an impedance that increases with motor speed. As such the max current becomes harder and harder to achieve with speed within a commutation cycle. Also, the motor may mechanically destroy itself at extreme speeds.

**EXTRA COOLING**

The other thing you can take into account is cooling. The motor will be specified at a certain ambient free flow air environment. If you can increase the air-flow over the rotor or otherwise extract heat from the core, you can in fact drive the motor harder with little significant effect on the motor other than reduced brush life.

**YOUR MOTOR**

Unfortunately E-Bay is a terrible place to buy stuff. Specifications and data sheet links are usually non existent. So knowing exactly what no load current = 3A is supposed to mean is anyone's guess. Plus, what you get in the mail is not always what's shown on the site. However, at <4$ a pop....

Comment: "Just hooking it up to a higher voltage will deliver more current than the motor is rated for." Not true. Current is related to torque, voltage to speed. At higher voltage the speed increases proportionally. Current increases only to the extent the load (or motor mechanical losses) require higher torque at higher speed. The current increase can be nearly insignificant or drastic depending on load characteristics. If the current is < rated at rated voltage because the load doesn't require the full motor capability, current may not exceed the rated value when the voltage is increased a little

Comment: @CharlesCowie yes, I meant the manufacturer normally specifies the motor to not burn out if powered on at that voltage with a locked rotor, or in some cases, a defined max torque. Hooking it up at a higher voltage than that will exceed those conditions. The rest of your comment is what I was saying.

Answer (score 3):

The specification says 3.7 volts, 22,000 RPM to 7.4 volts, 46,000 RPM. At 8 volts, the motor will run at about 49,700 RPM and at 9 volts, about 55,900 RPM. That increased speed will certainly shorten the life of the motor. It is difficult to estimate how much shorter the life will be. Other factors will also influence the life of the motor.

Increasing the voltage will not directly increase the current, but the load torque may increase due to increased speed and that would increase the current. If the motor is turning a propellor, the load torque and thus the current increase will be proportional to the square of the speed increase. For a propellor, \$\Big(\dfrac{8}{7.4}\Big)^2 = 1.17\$ current; \$\Big(\dfrac{9}{7.4}\Big)^2 = 1.48\$ current. If the motor draws rated current at 7.4 volts with the propellor you have, a current increase of nearly 50 percent will destroy the motor pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The motor can stay within its ratings if you add a few diodes, like this: 
If you don't need a reversible motor, you can omit D8, D9, and D10.
You may need higher rated diodes according to you motor's current requirements.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk8t8g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can run at 10 or 20% more voltage and of course aging will be faster.

All DC motors have a no load RPM/V ratio constant.  The upper RPM often depends on the commutation gap as arcing can bridge the rotor windings and begin to short out causing heat rise where aging rate doubles for every 10'C or so above ambient, so a hot brush and armature will fail much soon than a cool one.

The current thru the motor is controlled by acceleration from inertial load and then external load at a constant speed and both if accelerating from start at full voltage.

Since the starting current is always dictated by the winding Imax=V+/DCR , this is also up to 8x the rated current at full speed and obviously not sustainable. So 20% more voltage for brief spurts at full speed is not as bad as constant start stop braking at up to 800% x rated current.

But then 12.5% more V+ at 800%Imax means the starting current is now 10x rated current at full speed and full load, so don't plan on doing this consistently or for much longer durations than normal.  But intermittent spurts between say 25% and 75% of full speed with some duty factor or cooling between spurts would far better on the motor than like a electric car doing constant full speed acceleration and braking.

### Summary

try not to exceed max RPM to avoid commutation losses above rated RPM causing excessive arc temperature rise

try not to use 20% higher voltage at full acceleration from start but use PWM to only use full power after the back EMF has generated 20% of the voltage at 20% of rated RPM then adding 20% more V+ returns to the same starting torque at 0 RPM.

Keep in mind frequent full 8x current 0 to max RPM with load reduces lifetime perhaps more than spurts of 20% more V+ in the middle range to regulate speed faster  say with servo feedback.

Any excess current above Imax ( including I start/stop and raising V+) accelerates  more aging or wear and tear on  the commutation losses and affected parts.

It's like an automobile engine.  Sure you can redline it and add NOX to boost RPM but it will accelerate wear, but for brief  spurts with regulated acceleration and voltage within limits otherwise with PWM it's a big performance boost to be used sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

No. Like others have said, the motor is rated at 7.4 V so that should be it's max voltage. If you supply your motor with anything higher than this, it will try to draw more current than it should handle which will shorten its lifespan and possible spur other side effects (like increasing its temperature beyond operating temp).

Now, there is some room that the motor can tolerate but you should really supply the motor with its rated voltage.

Hope this helps.